# SQL Server - Restore Error 3202

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

While attempting to restore a 4 TB MDF/data database with a 1.8 TB LDF/log file, I'm receiving the following error:

> Write on '???' failed: 1117 (The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
>   Error: 3202, Severity: 16, State: 1

The backup appears to have created successfully on the primary machine, but will not restore to the backup machine. Both servers are running the SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition. The location of the `.LDF` transaction log file is being moved during the restore from the primary's I drive to the backups L drive, but this never posed an issue in the past.

The database is made up of 3 `.MDF` files: one approximately 2 TB, another at 1.4 TB, and another around 300 GB. The `.LDF` transaction log file is about 1.8TB. The restore locations have enough space, with the drive for the `.mdf` files having 6 TB total and the drive for `.ldf` having 2 TB total.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50133.aspx

Comment: Is that error message all there is? Is there an entry in the server log? At this point I'd find out the precise OS level error by using procmon.exe and looking at the IO at the time the error appears.

Comment: There are Windows level errors stating that there are failures at the disk level as well.  The restore process takes about 5 hours, so I'll try to get to it the next time it's about to complete.

Comment: Then I would like to encourage you to post all error information that you have!

Comment: @NoDisplayName, I checked the Write Caching link you mentioned and I did notice one of the drives did not have this enabled, so I enabled it.  I reran the Restore, but unfortunately had the same outcome.  Here is SQL Server's output at the time time of failure:

`95 percent processed.
96 percent processed.
97 percent processed.
Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Write on "???" failed: 1117(The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.`

Comment: There was also a Windows Log error entry at the same time:  `The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR1.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the error message posted in the comments this is a faulty disk that cannot serve write requests (at a certain location).

Comment: Eactly. Totally not related to the restore - this is faulty hardware. Fix it and it will work.

Comment: That was the issue.  The LUN was wiped out and recreated and now the errors are gone.  Thanks everyone for the assistance.